# forecasts salesforce

Tags: opportunity

I survey my salesforce instance and i see ForecastCategoryName has removed. I have found https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/collaborative_forecasts_setup/collaborative_forecasts_unit_1 but i don't found Forecasts Settings. This feature is removed ?

Comment: This appears to be an issue related to the EOL of Customizable Forecasting as described in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334120&type=1&mode=1. I recommend raising a support case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen such issues in the past, you need to [contact support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) to Enable Collaborative Forecasting in your org if not done already

Enabling Collaborative Forecasting requires disabling Customizable Forecasting. This involves executing a few steps sequentially at both ends. See [Enable Collaborative Forecasting to learn more](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334120&type=1&mode=1)

After support enables Collaborative forecasting, it is ready to use when you enable it from your end as well

Navigate to Customize --> Forecasts--> Forecasts Settings--> Check "Enable Forecasts".